# I need help with finding a polynomial and using it to find a perimeter

Tags: polynomials

So I need help with this problem, I’m new to polynomials.
Can you also explain how to get the answer?

Find the polynomial that models the problem and use it to estimate the quantity:

> A rectangle has a length of $x$ and a width of $5x^3 + 4 - x^2$.
>   Find the perimeter of the rectangle when the length is 5 feet.

Comment: Do you know the definitions of all the words (in particular: polynomial, Rectangle, length, width, perimeter) in the problem statement?

Comment: The perimeter of a rectangle is given by $2 \times (\mathrm{length} +\mathrm{width})$. Given $x = 5$ ft, you can use this to find to find the length and width. Then the aforementioned formula will give you the perimeter of the rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

The perimeter of a rectangle is $2($length$+$width$)$. Put the values of length and width. You'll get : 
Perimeter$=2×(x+5x^3+4-x^2)$. That's the polynomial of perimeter. Now put $x=5$, since the length$=5$. You'll get $2×(5+5×5^3+4-5^2) = 1218$. That's the required perimeter.

Comment: How did you get the second 2 In 2 X (2 + 5 X $5^3$ + 4 - $5^2$)

Comment: Ohh sorry, that should be $x=5$. My bad... Thanks for noticing it !!

Comment: Now check it... I think it's okay now. @reberror

Comment: Yeah it’s good now! @AnikBhowmick thanks for the help